# Want to download DIV as an IMAGE which is canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Hi guys i am trying to download an image of my div. for this i have tried following please guide me further.

```js
 $(function() { 
     $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
       html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                alert(theCanvas);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
       body {
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    
    }
    
    .dataset {
        float: left;
        vertical-align: top;
    
    
    }
    
    .widget {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        line-height: 20px !important;
    
        margin: 5px;
        vertical-align: top;
        color: #333;
    
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
    
    
        border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    
    
        display: inline-block;
        page-break-after: always;
    
    }
    
    .widget .header p {
       padding: 10px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
       max-width: 360px;
    }
    
    .widget .header .title {
        font-weight: bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        min-height: 36px;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    
    }
    
    .widget .header:hover {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    
    .widget .header  .title.selected {
        border-color: cornflowerblue;
        background-color: #EEF;
    
    }
    
    .widget .content {
        padding: 5px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .autolayout {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .element {
        width: 360px;
    }
    
    .compact .content {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .compact .row {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .compact .cell {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    
    .compact .row.selected {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    
    
    .toolbar {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .toolbar .basis {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
    
    .btn {
        /*min-width: 60px;*/
    }
    
    
    .cell.value {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-wrap: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .cell.freq {
        width: 60px;
    }
    
    .cell.glyph {
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100px;
    }
    
    
    .element {
    
    }
    .element table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .element td {
        padding: 0px;
    
    }
    
    .element .selectable:hover {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    
    
    .element .stat {
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-weigth: bold;
        color: darkgray;
    }
    
    
    
    .element .bar {
        height: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
    .bar-both {
        background-color: #0a67a3 !important;
    
    }
    
    .bar-fg {
        background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
    }
    
    .bar-bg {
        background-color: #ddd !important;
    }
    
    .selected .bar-fg {
        background-color: #FC0;
    }
    
    .selected .bar-both  {
        background-color:#FA0;
    }
    
    tr.selected {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    .crosstab .selectable:hover {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    
    .crosstab tr.selected {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    .crosstab .header p {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
    
    
    .crosstab td {
      padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .crosstab td.value {
      min-width: 60px;
      max-width: 240px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .crosstab .cell {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    
    
    .crosstab th.cell {
        max-width: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: normal;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .crosstab .n {
        color: darkgray;
    }
    .fieldlist {
    }
    
    .constraints {
        min-width:300px;
        padding: 10px;
    
        border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    
    
    }
    .constraints table {
        width: 100%;
    
    }
    
    .sidenote {
      max-width:300px;
      padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .headnote {
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .info-block {
        /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
        background-color: #eee;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    
        /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
    }
    
    .menu-item {
    }
    
    .menu-item-value {
        text-align: right;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .gradient-blue {
        background: #b8e1fc; /* Old browsers */
        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0); /* IE6-8 */
    }
```

```html
<span id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
        <div class="header ng-scope">
          <div class="title ng-binding">AGE</div>
          <p class="ng-binding">Patient age, in years</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element ng-scope">
          <div ng-show="hasData()" class="content">
            <table ng-model="table" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
              <colgroup>
                <col/>
                <col width="60x"/>
                <col width="100px"/>
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="cell value">Value</th>
                  <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
                  <th class="cell value"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="0" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19" class="ng-scope ng-binding">0 to 19</span>
                </td>
    
                <td class="cell freq ng-binding">17.2%</td>
                <td class="cell glyph">
                  <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="20" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39" class="ng-scope ng-binding">20 to 39</span>
                </td>
                <td class="cell freq ng-binding">18.0%</td>
                <td class="cell glyph">
                  <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="40" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59" class="ng-scope ng-binding">40 to 59</span>
                </td>
    
                <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
                <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
                <td class="cell glyph">
                  <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
                  <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="60" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79" class="ng-scope ng-binding">60 to 79</span>
                </td>

                <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
                <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
                <td class="cell glyph">
                  <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
                  <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="80" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99" class="ng-scope ng-binding">80 to 99</span>
                </td>
    
                <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
                <td class="cell freq ng-binding">6.4%</td>
                <td class="cell glyph">
                  <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
                  <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                  <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
              <tr ng-show="getShowMean()" class="">
                <td class="stat">Mean</td>
                <td class="ng-binding">46.1</td>
              </tr>
    
    
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    
    
        </div>
      <!-- ngRepeat: field in getChildren(field) -->
    </span>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>
```

i am using HTML2Canvas and filesaver library

the canvas element is in `theCanvas` this variable i am trying a function in which everything runs and on click of this `<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>` my image is downloaded..

thanks guyzz if someone helps